# Append an associative element to each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-map

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$template = Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 352 [name] => a ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 438 [name] => b ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 351 [name] => c ) 
)
```

and an array map function

```
function myfunction()
{
    return "[selected]=>null";
}
print_r(array_map("myfunction",$template));
```

which results in

```
Array ( 
   [0] => [selected]=>null 
   [1] => [selected]=>null 
   [2] => [selected]=>null
)
```

How do I map the array to get this result instead:

```
Array (  
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 352 [name] => a [selected] => null)  
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 438 [name] => b  [selected] => null)  
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 351 [name] => c  [selected] => null) 
)
```

Comment: This question has no question.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the value to each given array (inside the callback), like:

```
<?php

$in = [
    [ 'id' => 352, 'name' => 'a' ],
    [ 'id' => 438, 'name' => 'b' ],
    [ 'id' => 351, 'name' => 'c' ],
];

$out = array_map(function (array $arr) {
    // work on each array in the list of arrays
    $arr['selected'] = null;

    // return the extended array
    return $arr;
}, $in);

print_r($out);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/XHfLc

Answer (score 1):

you do not handle $template as an array, this is what your function should look like:

```
function myfunction($template)
{
    $template['selected'] = 'null';
    return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in some sort of way mentioned below,

```
function array_push_assoc(&$array, $key, $value){
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
        $array[$k][$key] = $value;
 return $array;
}
$result = array_push_assoc($template, 'selected','null');
print_r($result);
```

Adding to every index of associative array.

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2540cc650b5f83f8db9e2231be4b4b7394abf4b).

Answer (score 0):

Append the static/hardcoded associative element to each row of the 2d array using arrow function syntax and the "array union operator".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XHfLc))

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 352, 'name' => 'a'],
    ['id' => 438, 'name' => 'b'],
    ['id' => 351, 'name' => 'c'],
];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row + ['selected' = null],
        $array
    )
);
```